# wrong "permission denied" in linux?

Tags: linux, nfs, umask

```
root@SERVER:~# cat /etc/passwd | grep www-data
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh

root@SERVER:~# ls -al /cluster/www/html/tmp/reportexport_274.xml
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 908 2011-03-30 14:03 /cluster/www/html/tmp/reportexport_274.xml

root@SERVER:~# sudo -u www-data cat /cluster/www/html/tmp/reportexport_274.xml
cat: /cluster/www/html/tmp/reportexport_274.xml: Permission denied
```

The directory is an nfs mount:

```
x:/cluster/www /cluster/www nfs _netdev,rw,soft,intr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,nosuid,nodev,noatime,timeo=15 0 0
```

> Linux x 2.6.32-31-server #61-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 19:44:42 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

How can this be? am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

How about `sudo -u www-data ls -l /cluster/www/html/tmp/`? Perhaps www-data is missing permissions to reach the directory entry. If that's the case `chown`/`chmod` each directory up to `tmp` so they are readable/executable by www-data.

Comment: sudo -u www-data ls -l /cluster/www/html/tmp/*.xml

ls: cannot access /cluster/www/html/tmp/export_274.xml: Permission denied

Comment: @user80973: do `sudo -u www-data ls -ld /cluster/www/html/tmp`, `sudo -u www-data ls -ld /cluster/www/html`, etc. until it doesn't result in an error or you get to /cluster. You have to change the permissions in the directories giving permission errors by using `chmod a+rx /path/to/dir`. At the very least you'll probably have to execute `chmod a+rx /cluster/www/html/tmp`.

Comment: yeh it was missing the lack of +x . :)

Answer (score 0):

Check that the directories in the path all in some manner allow user `www-data` read and execute permission.